# Default parameters: can only the last argument(s) be left?

Tags: c++, default-parameters

I know **it's possible** to do something like :

```
int foo(int a = 0, int b = 1) { return a + b; }
```

and then use it without the default parameters eg.:

```
foo();    // a = 0, b = 1 -> 1
```

or with the last one as default eg.:

```
foo(2);    // a = 2 and b = 1 default -> 3
```

But **my question is**:
Is it possible to use the default value for the first argument (a) and give the value of the second (b)

My first thought was doing it like (**which doesn't work!**):

```
foo(,2);    // a = 0 default and b = 2
```

Does a syntax for this exist 
or is this just not possible ?

Comment: Nope, it can't be done.

Comment: Closely related; http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39818748/what-should-the-default-argumentif-any-be-while-passing-a-vector-to-a-function

Comment: it is not possible; default parameters must be rightmost

Answer (score 22, accepted):

No,  it is not possible in current syntax.

Answer (score 8):

Alternatively from specifying default parameter values you can use multiple function overloads like:

```
 int foo(int a, int b){return a+b; }
 int foo(int b){return foo(0,b); }     
 int foo(){return foo(0,1); }
```

Comment: Wouldn't this have the same effect as `foo(int b=1, int a=0){..}` ?

Comment: @UNKN57 Well, yes. But a different effect from `int foo(int a=0, int b=1)`. And you can't declare both, because of ambiguity.

Comment: maybe my example wasn't the best. What i wanted was to use the first parameter with the default value and hand over values for arguments to the right (which, as i know now is not possible).

Comment: @UNKN57 May be your example was oversimplified. There are more variations possible with my proposal regarding disambiguate parameter types.

Comment: @UNKN57: It's unclear to me how this is not doing exactly what you want. If you call `foo(2)` it will be as if you called `foo(0, 2)`. Isn't that exactly what you were trying to do in your example?

Comment: @Benjamin Lindley Yes i wanted to do this, but i wanted to still be able to call foo(2) for foo(2,1). Obviously this can not work if you try to declare 2 methods. So i thought there might be some special syntax (like my idea with the kommata).

Comment: @UNKN57 I doubt that kind of syntax will be implemented into c++ soon.

Comment: For the left-out parameters, a special type can be used in the overloads, e.g. https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/optional/nullopt_t Then all combinations are possible Of course the parameters themselves can be `std::optional` instead in the first place; then no overloads are needed

Comment: Why not using something like `int foo({.b=2});` where foo accepts an aggregate initialized with: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/aggregate_initialization

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible directly. However, it is possible somehow if you declare a struct for the input parameters that encapsulates the default values and has individual setters:

```
#include <iostream>
 
struct Foo{
    int a,b;
    Foo() : a(0),b(1) {};
    Foo setA(int x) { a=x; return *this;}
    Foo setB(int x) { b=x; return *this;}
};
 
void foo(Foo f = Foo()){ std::cout << f.a << "  " << f.b << std::endl; }
 
int main() {
    foo();                // uses default values for a and b
    foo(Foo().setA(3));   // uses default value for b
    foo(Foo().setB(5));   // uses default value for a
}
```

Comment: Why not combining Aggregate initialisation with an aggregate as function parameter? https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/aggregate_initialization

Comment: @FabianKeßler there is no "why not". The point of the answer is just to use a custom struct

Comment: an aggregate is also a custom struct, but it does not require the setters: https://godbolt.org/z/9556jqard

Comment: @FabianKeßler I know, if it works for you go for it. This answer is from 2016 when c++20 was not widely available. Consider this: https://godbolt.org/z/7hK33dnac

Comment: Yes, I know, that this is a c++20 feature. I am only curious, why this question was shown on the front page of my feed. Nevertheless, you could/can add the c++ aggregate version for c++20 users to your answer.

Answer (score 1):

Once we provide a default value for a parameter, all subsequent parameters must also have default values. For example,

```
// Invalid
void add(int a, int b = 3, int c, int d);

// Invalid
void add(int a, int b = 3, int c, int d = 4);

// Valid
void add(int a, int c, int b = 3, int d = 4);
```

Answer (score 1):

Though still not possible the way OP expects, there is since [c++17](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b17) a way to mimic this behaviour using [`std::optional`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/optional).

Instead of passing `int` as arguments, pass `optional<int>` with default value of `{}`:

```cpp
int foo(std::optional<int> in_a = {}, std::optional<int> in_b = {});
```

Then replace in the function body by the "real" default values if the user did not provide a value (`{}` or `std::nullopt` was passed):

```cpp
int foo(std::optional<int> in_a = {}, std::optional<int> in_b = {})
{
    const auto a = in_a.value_or(default_value_for_a);
    const auto b = in_b.value_or(default_value_for_b);

    return a + b;
}
```

For example, assuming you want default value of `a` but not `b`, you now do:

```cpp
foo({}, value_for_b);
```

This generalises well when more parameters are added. The only restriction is that you must be able to put the type in `optional`, [which has some restrictions](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/optional) regarding this.

Answer (score 0):

I know that it is not really an answer to your question, but you could try to use [boost named parameters](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_61_0/libs/parameter/doc/html/index.html). It might be useful for your use case.

Comment: i hadn't had an actual usecase. Just aked this myself while learning (im an absolute c++ newbie). But your link seems very helpful!

Answer (score -2):

no it is not possible
first parameter has to be filled by some value

Comment: This provides no more information than the accepted answer